# How to show custom error on Application startup?

Tags: angular

In `Index.html`, I can show alert or write error in browser console like this-

```
System.import('app').catch(function (err)
{
    alert("Error occurred while loading application!!");
    console.error(err);
});
```

But Loading text from this line remains on screen-

```
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

How do I change this loading text and show custom error message on angular2 application startup?

Comment: Chicken-egg egg-chicken paradigm, if you can't initialize app you can't put message in it

Comment: Is there any alternative? because user keep seeing Loading message.